# Reading an array of points from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, three.js

I am having trouble reading in data from a JSON file.  I have gone through the other reading JSON questions on Stack Overflow and the JSON docs to no avail.

I am trying to read in data to be displayed in Three.js.  The following snippet works:

```
var obj = { "points" : [
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[200.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[-200.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,100.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,-100.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,300.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,-300.0] },
{ "vertex":[75.0,75.0,75.0] },
{ "vertex":[50.0,50.0,50.0] },
{ "vertex":[25.0,25.0,25.0] } ]};

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = obj.points[i].vertex[0];
    vertex.y = obj.points[i].vertex[1];
    vertex.z = obj.points[i].vertex[2];
    geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}
```

It reads in the points and the points are rendered further down the line.  I have a file next to the index.html named

> test.json

it contains the following:

```
{ "points" : [
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[200.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[-200.0,0.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,100.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,-100.0,0.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,300.0] },
{ "vertex":[0.0,0.0,-300.0] },
{ "vertex":[75.0,75.0,75.0] },
{ "vertex":[50.0,50.0,50.0] },
{ "vertex":[25.0,25.0,25.0] } 
]}
```

My problem is that the following doesn't work (i.e. doesn't display the points):

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

var obj2 = jQuery.getJSON('test.json');

for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = obj2.points[i].vertex[0];
    vertex.y = obj2.points[i].vertex[1];
    vertex.z = obj2.points[i].vertex[2];
    geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}
```

The files are in the public folder of my dropbox and viewed from the public link, even so, just in case i'm running chrome with the --allow-files-access-from-files flag.

UPDATE

My key mistake was not processing the vertices in the callback of the getJSON function.  My secondary mistake was assuming that adding the vertices to the geometry stack in the callback was enough.  In fact I had to create the object from the geometry and add it to the scene for it to work.  Many thanks for everyones help.

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(obj2) {

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.x = obj2.points[i].vertex[0];
        vertex.y = obj2.points[i].vertex[1];
        vertex.z = obj2.points[i].vertex[2];
        geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
    }

    vc1 = geometry.vertices.length;

    object = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, shaderMaterial );
    object.dynamic = true;

    var vertices = object.geometry.vertices;
    var values_size = attributes.size.value;
    var values_color = attributes.ca.value;

    for( var v = 0; v < vertices.length; v ++ ) {
    values_size[ v ] = 50;
    values_color[ v ] = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    }

    scene.add( object );
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't render any of the points. Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the docs for [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), it is an asynchronous call!

You need to put the for loop in in the callback.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Javascript. Do you mean to structure it like in Max Burucker's answer?

Comment: Yes and you need to have whatever renders the object inside of the callback too. Not just the code you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it like this

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(obj2) {
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
vertex.x = obj2.points[i].vertex[0];
vertex.y = obj2.points[i].vertex[1];
vertex.z = obj2.points[i].vertex[2];
geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}
});
```

Edit1 
typo

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are doing there but it still doesn't display the points when I replace my code with that above.

Comment: Thank you, your code gave me a solid starting point. I also had to create the object from the geometry and add it to the scene for it to work, all within the callback.

Comment: @StuGrey Could you please share the I also need to read a json file for positions of points in three js buffer geometry points.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like tiny mistake.
You can do following:

1) Check whether test.json is referenced in your html page or not?

2) Use firebug (console tab) to check exactly what is returned by getJson method